# Android SharedPreferences gets cleared?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preferences as I always do, but recently in a new application the cache suddenly returns null,

here are the methods for read/write

```
public static void saveToSharedPreferences(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
        if (mSharedPreferences != null)
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }
}

public static String readFromSharedPreferences(Context mContext, String key) {      
    if (mContext != null) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);

        if (mSharedPreferences != null)
            return mSharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

then in the code

```
Utils.saveToSharedPreferences(getActivity(), mKey, mDATA);
```

in the same session when using

```
String mDATA = Utils.readFromSharedPreferences(getActivity(), mKey);
```

it does return the value, but later on when exiting the app and lauching it again, it returns null, everything seems to be fine

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the Context you're using is not NULL?
Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit(); 
editor.putString(key, value); 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, try creating a new Editor instance instead of inline:
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences .edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();

Comment: thank you, MODE_WORLD_READABLE seems to have solved the problem "for now", I will come back to this if it still persist, thanks

Comment: the problem still persists

Comment: Please check my edited answer (create a new SharedPreferences.Editor)